# IOS Change Accessory View Cell Image in Uitableview based on NSMutableArray value

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uiimageview, nsmutablearray

I have a `UITableview` That I display a list of users and their profile pictures. On the right hand side of the `UITableview` I have added a image for the Cell Accessory View.

I have a `NSMutableArray` "isFollowingLeader" that has 2 different values in it. 0 and 1 being the values stored in my array.

I want to be able to change or set the `cell.accessoryView` based on the isFollowingLeader array.

So If the isFollowingLeader array is 0 at index path of `UITableview` I want to set the image of the `cell.accessoryView` to my image of ic_add_contact.png at index path of `UITableview` and if the array is 1 at index path I want to show ic_checkmark_square.png

```
isFollowingLeader Array in NSlog (
1,
0,
0,
0,
1,
0,
0,
0
)

self.isFollowingLeader = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:[prefs arrayForKey:@"piccingFollowerisLeader"]];


if ([self.isFollowingLeader objectAtIndex:[indexPath row]] == 0) {

    // Sets the image for the  Accessory View for cell
    UIImageView *arrow = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"ic_add_contact.png"]];
    cell.accessoryView = arrow;
}

else  {

    // Sets the image for the  Accessory View for cell
    UIImageView *arrow = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"ic_checkmark_square.png"]];
    cell.accessoryView = arrow;
}
```

[image]

Comment: What is your question? you not said whats not working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not entirely sure what your question is, I'm assuming its not working for you?

This line is wrong....

```
if ([self.isFollowingLeader objectAtIndex:[indexPath row]] == 0)
```

You are asking if the object is 0, not the value of the object, so it should be

```
if ([[self.isFollowingLeader objectAtIndex:[indexPath row]] integerValue] == 0)
```